# How to make back up of Android Studio?

Tags: windows, android-studio, backup

i am installing Windows & on my Laptop by cleaning C drive in which android studio is installed and i wanna take backup of the full Android Studio Application, because i dont want to download and install  whole 1.7GB again.

any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back up your application

STEP 1.

-> Your default folder path located at DOCUMENTS->AndroidStudioProject
   Then Copy all the projects and paste to one folder.

-> If your projects are not located in the default folder project then it is
   fine. Copy all your project that is not located in default folder path.

STEP 2.

-> If you want to back up your SDK make it sure that you know the default
   location for your SDK's then copy the root file of it to your one folder
   then when you install again Android Studio paste it all.

-> If you don't want to copy your SDK then skip STEP 2.

STEP 3.

-> If you are done copying all the files and projects/SDK then compress or 
   use compression file software like WinRar/7zip.

STEP 4.

-> After you install again Android Studio , paste all your copied file. But 
   make sure that you extract it .

****NOTE****

-> Location of your SDK "[Can be C or D]:[Name of DRIVE][Name of USER account]\AppData\Local\Android"

Answer (score 2):

I reinstalled Windows and this is what I did to take backup of complete Android Studio along with the updates and your project files. I hope the detailed answer will be helpful for new developers. My Android Studio installation was at D:\BaseInstall\android-studio so the example paths are specific to my installation and you will have to change the path as per your installation. Please refer to the attached image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a zip file of your Android studio application and also SDK. You can copy paste it on any other machine then, just need to change the path of sdk in your studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy and keep android SDK folder (So that you don't perform large download).
2. Copy android-studio-bundle if you had downloaded early or [download](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) latest one.
3. Once you finish you OS installation, move SDK folder, just install java/JRE and start android studio
4. Set the SDK path in android studio preference or installation wizard dialog.
5. Set environment variable,  JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_HOME in windows environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I use [rclone](https://rclone.org/downloads/) and sync my Android projects folder to Google Drive (it also supports One Drive and others).

You could do something similar, but do the entire Android Studio installation.

In my Android Studio launcher (studio.sh), I modify the file so that the project folder is synced from Google Drive to my hard drive on startup, and synced back to Google Drive on close down.

This is mainly because I do development on different computers.

My studio.sh looks something like below

```
#################################################
# Put the following at start of studio.sh file  #
# Sync any new updated source files from GDrive #
#------------------------------------------------
rclone sync -L GDrive: home/me/AndroidStudioProjects


#################################################
# Put the following at end of studio.sh file    #
# Sync files back to GDrive                     #
#------------------------------------------------
rclone sync -L home/me/AndroidStudioProjects GDrive:
```

The above will only work if rclone is in your execution path obviously, and also you have to be careful how you shut down Android Studio (close your project, then AS).

However, this works really nicely for me.

rclone also supports at rest encryption (which I use) so your project doesn't have to be in plaintext whilst in cloud storage, and it decrypts the data on the fly when you want to sync it back down.

It's an awesome free tool really.